# how to make findby with composite key in spring data - jpa -hibernate ? @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, composite-key, embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class AccountTransactionId implements Serializable {
    private String trxDate;
    private String acctNo;
    private int trxNo;
}

@Entity
public class Transaction {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountTransactionId accountTransactionId;

    private int amt;
    private int fee;
    private String cancelYn;
}
```

this is my repository. how to make the find method? i don't have any idea about that

```
List<Map<String, Object>> findByAccountTransactionId_trxDate(String trxDate);
```

i tried "findByAccountTransactionId_trxDate", "findByAccountTransactionIdTrxDate", "findByIdTrxDate"...

Comment: Please share your whole interface of Repository

Answer (score 9):

You could use @IdClass (https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-composite-primary-key)

Then you can just pass the class in the example in the link, it would be

```
repository.findById(new AccoutId(accountno,accounttype)
```

This worked for me

Comment: can you please remove the link and put your answer here ?

Comment: You could use @IdClass

Then you can just pass the class in the example in the link, it would be
repository.findById(new AccoutId(accountno,accounttype)
This worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I suggest having a look over the camel case if will change something; probably there is going to not work because of that.

Second, I would expect the method to return a list of objects, instead of a map. In your case, this is the solution I expect to work:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, AccountTransactionId> {

    /**
      * here rename accountTransactionId to id 
      * and trxDate to trxdate
      */
    List<Object> findByIdTrxdate(String trxDate, String acctNo); 
    List<Object> findByAccountTransactionIdTrxDate(String trxDate, String acctNo);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write like this:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, AccountTransactionId> {

    List<Map<String, Object>> findByTrxDateAndAcctNo(String trxDate, String acctNo);

}
```

Comment: you are the one that i am waiting for

Comment: Check below example for more details:- 

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-composite-primary-key-example/

Comment: As far as I can tell this will throw an exception because type Transaction has no property trxDate

Comment: the way around this would be to declare parts of the composite key as individual fields of the entity (second time), and mark them with updatable=false, insertable=false